# Where do I put my django Template Context Processor setting in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to migrate an old project over from Django 1.6 to 1.10.

I have read the documentation but I am still having trouble understand how to handle Templates in my settings.py

In my old settings I had:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",

]
```

How do I migrate this over to 1.10?  Can I add it to the following?

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, 'templates')],
}]
```

Currently when I run my Django project in 1.10, I get an error that says TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8

Comment: The Django docs cover [upgrading templates to Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/upgrading/#upgrading-templates-to-django-1-8). You might find it easier to upgrade to Django 1.8 first (possibly via Django 1.7), rather than jumping straight to Django 1.10. That will give you a chance to fix deprecation warnings in 1.8, rather than getting errors in Django 1.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now your template option should look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```